# Mathematica SE Popularity

Tags: discussion

I saw this [plot](http://sogrady-media.redmonk.com/sogrady/files/2015/01/lang.rank_.plot_.q1152.png) the other day and was amazed at how much of an outlier *Mathematica* is. Not necessarily in how little it is on GitHub, but how popular it is on the y-axis.

Which got me wondering... why? Is the language that hard to learn? Is the language so powerful that questions keep on popping up pushing its limits? Combination?

Somewhat related. I was reading this [*Mathematica* vs *Maple*](https://www.maplesoft.com/products/maple/compare/HowMapleComparestoMathematica.pdf) comparison. Now I know this is a marketing piece, but holy crap, some of that *Mathematica* coding is downright awful (the `Slider` example is really funny). With misinformation like that floating around, it's no wonder people are flocking here!

Comment: [A related thread on main.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60124)

Comment: My at most second-hand understanding is that WRI is not particularly welcoming towards Home Edition users publishing polished source code or packages which would be beneficial to professional licensees. This might affect amount and setting of people writing Wolfram Language software in Github, especially considering the cost of a professional license. Or am I mistaken on this?

Comment: @kirma, welp, there goes 90% of everything I've done in *Mathematica*…

Comment: Pity the poor person who tries to turn to SO for help with their BlitzBasic Github project.

Comment: I'm surprised about the position of TeX.  I thought LaTeX was the best example of something that almost everyone uses but almost no one knows really well.

Comment: @kirma I've never heard that before, is that really so?  Sounds disturbing.

Comment: @Szabolcs I wish I would could provide a source for this memory. I can't guarantee it isn't either plainly wrong, or a misunderstanding of something somebody said...

Comment: I asked the creator of this plot about this a while back. Note that the y axis is not including the Mathematica Stack Exchange posts, just the older posts that used to be tagged with [mathematica].

Comment: @ArnoudBuzing well, that turns futile any reasoning about it

Comment: @ArnoudBuzing Crazy.

Comment: Mmmm... let me gue$$...

Comment: @ArnoudBuzing have you suggested him to include the Mathematica.SE posts as well? If so, what was his position on this?

Comment: I wonder if it's driven in part by the fact that `.nb` files don't version control very well – so putting code on github is gated by the need to first understand packages, `.m` files, etc.

Comment: @shrx I did, but he feels that his analysis is more consistent by just using tags from the base Stack Exchange.

Comment: I keep meaning to transition some of my stuff to github, but life intrudes.

Comment: One piece that is missing here is that until about a year or so ago, _Mathematica_ projects were **incorrectly** classified as Objective-C because both used the `.m` file extension. Now github is good at recognizing it as _Mathematica_, but it requires a new commit to rebuild the indexes before existing projects can be classified as such.

Comment: Maybe people who use expensive proprietary software are rather prone to do proprietary stuff with it? Some NSA-tool for machine learning for example might not figure "popular" or "wide-spread" on such a diagram; but what would it tell us? ;-)